How to retrieve a data value from a nested json file using Progress 4GL
How to get the value of Example: "JournalNum" from the below json Object
{"parameters":{"ds":{"GLJrnHed":[{"Company":"EPIC06"}]}}

My code for a non nested JSON is below
TJsonObject = CAST(oResponse:Entity, JsonObject).
OP-JOURNAL-NUM = INTEGER(TJsonObject:getJsonText("Company")).

In this case, It won't work because JournalNum is not open directly in the JSON.
I just need only this field , so diverting all data into temp-table via read-json is an expensive option.

I assume you are trying to get the "Company" value - not "JournalNum. Assumption is based on your code sample.

You'll have to go the long way down the rabbit hole
TJsonObject = CAST(oResponse:Entity, JsonObject). 

OP-JOURNAL-NUM = TJsonObject:GetJsonObject ("parameters"):GetJsonObject ("ds"):GetJsonArray ("GLJrnHed"):GetJsonObject (1):GetCharacter ("Company").

